# can't adapt type 'SimpleLazyObject' with get_context_data (Class Based View)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django web app deployed to Heroku.
App is deployed and working well, except for the related issue.

Some specs :

1. In my local env I use SQLite 3 DB
2. In Heroku env I use Postgress DB

When I try to render a class based view this error happens to me:

> can't adapt type 'SimpleLazyObject'

After some checks about this issue I suspect it is related to the User object. but i don't know how to approach it.

View Code:

```
class ProfileListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_list.html'

    context_object_name = 'qs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(self.request.user)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    return context
```

URL :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProfileListView.as_view(), name='all-profiles-view'),
]
```

Customize manager:

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_profiles(self, me):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all().exclude(user=me)
        return profiles
```

**EDIT:**

It likely seems the source of the problem is related to :

```
user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems from `get_queryset`. Because django adds a user attribute to request that is an instance of SimpleLazyObject. Since your error traceback shows it was problem with `SimpleLazyObject`, I suspect the problem comes from `request.user` could be either an object of User or anonymous user. So, it the following answer, I tried to add if statement to make sure that only the authenticated user will have qs.

You can tweak it a bit for your needs.

try replace with

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs= []
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
             qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(self.request.user)
        return qs
```

Comment: I've copy-paste your code, but I still get error 
can't adapt type 'SimpleLazyObject'

Comment: what is your get_all_profiles? could you show that part?

Comment: does the get_all_profiles involve ```filter```?

Comment: I've edited my post for your demand, have a look.
It's a customized manager.

Comment: Update: It's seems that ```user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)``` causing the problem, i've deleted it and changed ```profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)``` . it woks