# First time deploying a django app on Heroku and I'm facing 2 issues, solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, django-models

I've worked on my social app and been able to deploy it and I'm having 2 problems:
Link: https://network50web.herokuapp.com/
1/It directs me autmatically to https://network50web.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/?next=/ and I'm only able to see the site if I write the routes manually in the address bar like(login, register)

2/When I try to login it with my existent username it throws error "Programming Error at /login

relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user..." and it highlights this line "            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)" even when I try to register a new account
I used SQL for the database
Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, request
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, resolve_url, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from itertools import chain


from .models import Relationship, Post, Profile, Like
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, DetailView
from .forms import ProfileModelForm, PostModelForm, CommentModelForm

def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        profiles = Profile.objects.filter(slug__contains=searched)
        return render(request, 'network/search.html',
        {'searched':searched,
        'profiles':profiles})
    else:
        return render(request, 'network/search.html',
        {})



class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-view')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)

        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["posts"] = self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()
        context["len_posts"] = True if len(self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()) > 0 else False

        return context



@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    confirm = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
        'confirm': confirm,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', context)

@login_required
def invites_received_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    qs = Relationship.objects.invitations_received(profile)
    results = list(map(lambda x: x.sender, qs))
    is_empty = False
    if len(results) == 0:
        is_empty = True

    context = {
        'qs':results,
        'is_empty': is_empty,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/invites.html', context)

@login_required
def accept_invitation(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        if rel.status == 'send':
            rel.status = 'accepted'
            rel.save()

    return redirect('invites-view')

@login_required
def reject_invitation(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        rel.delete()
    return redirect('invites-view')

@login_required
def invite_profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles_to_invite(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/to_invite_list.html', context)

@login_required
def profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/profile_list.html', context)

class ProfileListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile_list.html'
    #context_object_name = 'qs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(self.request.user)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["is_empty"] = False
        if len(self.get_queryset()) == 0:
            context["is_empty"] = True

        return context

@login_required
def send_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.create(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, status='send')

        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')

@login_required
def remove_friends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.get(
            (Q(sender=sender) & Q(receiver=receiver)) | (Q(sender=receiver) & Q(receiver=sender))
        )
        rel.delete()
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')

@login_required
def like_unlike_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        if profile in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(profile)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(profile)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=profile, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Unlike'
            else:
                like.value='Like'
        else:
            like.value='Unlike'

            post_obj.save()
            like.save()

        data = {
            'value': like.value,
            'likes': post_obj.liked.all().count()
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return redirect('posts')

@login_required
def post_comment_create_view(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    #Setting up pagination
    p = Paginator(qs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = p.get_page(page)

    #Post form, comment form
    p_form = PostModelForm()
    c_form = CommentModelForm()
    post_added = False

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if 'submit_pForm' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = PostModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            instance = p_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            p_form = PostModelForm()
            post_added = True

    if 'submit_cForm' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'qs': qs,
        'profile': profile,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'c_form': c_form,
        'post_added': post_added,
        'post_list': post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/posts.html', context)

@login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    posts = []
    qs = None

    for u in users:
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.post_set.all()
        posts.append(p_posts)

    my_posts = profile.get_my_posts()
    posts.append(my_posts)
    if len(posts) > 0:
            my_posts = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj: obj.created)

    #Setting up pagination
    p = Paginator(my_posts, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = p.get_page(page)

    #Post form, comment form
    p_form = PostModelForm()
    c_form = CommentModelForm()
    post_added = False

    if 'submit_pForm' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = PostModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            instance = p_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            p_form = PostModelForm()
            post_added = True

    if 'submit_cForm' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'posts': qs,
        'profile': profile,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'c_form': c_form,
        'post_added': post_added,
        'post_list': post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/followers_posts.html', context)

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/confirmDelete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if not obj.author.user == self.request.user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You need to be the owner of the post in order to delete it!')
        return obj

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = PostModelForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if form.instance.author == profile:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, "You need to be the owner of the post in order to update it!")
            return super().form_invalid(form)


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("posts"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("all-profiles-view"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views
from .views import (
    posts_of_following_profiles,
    like_unlike_post,
    invites_received_view,
    invite_profiles_list_view,
    send_invitation,
    remove_friends,
    accept_invitation,
    reject_invitation,
    search_view,
    post_comment_create_view,
    login_view,
    logout_view,
    register,


    ProfileDetailView,
    PostDeleteView,
    PostUpdateView,
    ProfileListView,
    #EditProfileView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path("", ProfileListView.as_view(), name="all-profiles-view"),
    path("posts/", views.post_comment_create_view, name="posts"),
    path("posts-follow/", posts_of_following_profiles, name="posts-follow"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("liked/", like_unlike_post, name="like-post-view"),
    path("<pk>/delete", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("<pk>/update", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("invites/", invites_received_view, name="invites-view"),
    path("send-invite/", send_invitation, name="send-invite"),
    path("remove-friend/", remove_friends, name="remove-friend"),
    path("invites/accept/", accept_invitation, name="accept-invite"),
    path("invites/reject/", reject_invitation, name="reject-invite"),
    path("to-invite/", invite_profiles_list_view, name='invite-profiles-view'),
    path("search/", views.search_view, name='search-view'),
    path("<slug>", ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile-view"),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core import validators
from django.db import models
from itertools import chain
import random
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
from django.shortcuts import reverse

from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from .utils import get_random_code
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db.models import Q


class ProfileManager(models.Manager):

    def get_all_profiles_to_invite(self, sender):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all().exclude(user=sender)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=sender)
        qs = Relationship.objects.filter(Q(sender=profile) | Q(receiver=profile))

        accepted = set([])
        for rel in qs:
            if rel.status == 'accepted':
                accepted.add(rel.receiver)
                accepted.add(rel.sender)
        print(accepted)

        available = [profile for profile in profiles if profile not in accepted]

        return available


    def get_all_profiles(self, me):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all().exclude(user=me)
        return profiles

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='avatar.png')
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', default='background.png')
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default="No Bio..")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


    __initial_first_name = None
    __initial_last_name = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__initial_first_name = self.first_name
        self.__initial_last_name = self.last_name


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ex = False
        to_slug = self.slug
        if self.first_name != self.__initial_first_name or self.last_name != self.__initial_last_name or self.slug=="":
            if self.first_name and self.last_name:
                to_slug = slugify(str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name))
                ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
                while ex:
                    to_slug = slugify(to_slug + " " + str(get_random_code()))
                    ex = Profile.objects.filter(slug=to_slug).exists()
            else:
                to_slug = str(self.user)
        self.slug = to_slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.following.all()

    def get_followers_num(self):
        return self.following.all().count()


    def get_my_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all()

    def get_country(self):
        return self.post_set.all()


    def get_following_users(self):
        following_list = [p for p in self.get_following()]
        return following_list

    def get_followers_users(self):
        following_list = [p for p in self.get_followers()]
        return following_list

    def get_all_posts(self):
        users = [user for user in self.get_following()]
        posts = []
        qs = None
        for u in users:
            p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
            p_posts = p.post_set.all()
            posts.append(p_posts)
        my_posts = self.post_set.all()
        posts.append(my_posts)
        if len(posts) > 0:
            qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj: obj.created)
        return qs

    def get_posts_num(self):
        return self.post_set.all().count()

    def get_all_authors_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all()

    def get_likes_given_num(self):
        likes = self.like_set.all()
        total_liked = 0
        for item in likes:
            if item.value == 'Like':
                total_liked += 1
        return total_liked

    def get_likes_received_num(self):
        posts = self.post_set.all()
        total_liked = 0
        for item in posts:
            total_liked += item.all().count()
        return total_liked

    def get_proposals_for_following(self):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all().exclude(user=self.user)
        followers_list = [p for p in self.get_following()]
        available = [p.user for p in profiles if p.user not in followers_list]
        random.shuffle(available)
        return available[:3]


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('send', 'send'),
    ('accepted', 'accepted')
)

class RelationshipManager(models.Manager):
    def invitations_received(self, receiver):
        qs = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=receiver, status='send')
        return qs

class Relationship(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = RelationshipManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sender}-{self.receiver}-{self.status}"


class Post(models.Model):
    # id is created automatically by Django
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])])
    content = models.TextField()
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name="likes")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.content[:20])

    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()

    @property
    def like_count(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()

    def get_user_liked(self, user):
        pass

    # Number of comments
    def num_comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all.count()


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike'),
)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}-{self.post}-{self.value}"

    def like_numb(self):
        return self.like.all().count()
```

Settings:

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = secretkey

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'network',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project4.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (BASE_DIR, 'network/templates'),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'network/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR, 'network/static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: It says the relation auth user does not exist. After hosting the app did you migrate it?

Comment: I'm supposed to do that again? OKay so I migrate it and push it again or what are the steps exactly? @SamarJyotiNath

Comment: 1)You've to set ***``LOGIN_URL``*** and ***``LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL``*** in settings.py file. 2) you've to run makemigrations & migrate commands.

Comment: Walk me through those steps please, how do I do that? @AnkitTiwari

Comment: Hello @devstuff did you followed any tutorials ?

Comment: Login to your heroku account, click on your app, then open "run console". Type your migrations command there.

Comment: Okay that kinda worked but I still can't login with my old username, it's like the database doesn't exist anymore so I tried to register a new user and it says "can't adapt type 'SimpleLazyObject'" and it highlights this line "user =User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)" @SamarJyotiNath

Comment: Check this out, it might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325121/cant-adapt-type-simplelazyobject-with-get-context-data-class-based-view

Comment: Done thank you, but how can i use my old database that I already created with its user, posts, and my superuser. I don't need to create another superuser @AnkitTiwari

Comment: If you've your old data in database then you can follow [django fixtures](https://dev.to/hussainislam/django-fixtures-seeding-databases-5ai) or you can go form [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

Comment: All worked, thank you so much guys! While I have you here, can you help me out with the editprofile form to make it work? @AnkitTiwari

Comment: @SamarJyotiNath editprofile form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you've to set your ***`LOGIN_URL`*** and ***`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`*** inside your settings.py file like this

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Second login to your heroku cli and run this command

```
$ heroku run bash
```

this will open a bash for you from there you can access your project files
you've to navigate to your project root dir *(where manage.py lies)* and then run these two commands

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations network
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Done thank you, but how can i use my old database that I already created with its user, posts, and my superuser. I don't need to create another superuser @AnkitTiwari